# using java anonymous functions to return values

Tags: java, lambda

Transitioning from C# to Java and attempting to clean up a bunch of Connection leaks in some code.

To prevent leaks in I would have done something like

```
public class DB{
    public interface StatementUser{
         public void useit(Statement cmd);
    }

    public static void UseCommand(StatementUser usingfunc){
        try(Connection cnn = new Connection(...)){
            cnn.open();
            try(Statement stmt = new Statement(cnn)){
                usingfunc(stmt);
            }
        }
    }

    static void main(string[] args){
        int affected = 0;
        DB.useStatement((stmt) -> {
            // THIS STATEMENT IS DISALLOWED
            affected = ... select/update... whatever
        });
        System.out.println("Records: " + affected);
    }
}
```

I like this delegate because it handles the cleanup but still leaves most of the interaction with the data to the developer's creativity.

I get that the assignment to `affected` is considered accessing a variable outside of its scope, and not allowed. So now I'm kind of at a loss as to how to perform a similar operation in Java (I want to maintain the generic usage of the connection/statement object)

Everything I've come up with just makes it uglier, so I suspect I'm simply heading down a completely dead-end path.

What is a Java way of doing something like this? (I get that this may look drastically different than I'm expecting)

Comment: Where exactly is the disallowed variable access? This approach looks okay.

Comment: If you mean assigning to `affected`, maybe that should be a return value of the lambda (as opposed to the `void` you have now). Otherwise, you could use an updatable container class (such as AtomicInteger here).

Comment: The updateable container class was the path I was starting to dislike. I was starting to have visions of a bunch of quick classes being smattered throughout the code. I was unaware of a pre-existing `AtomicInteger`, which gives a nice interface as well.

Comment: @Thilo the more I think about it, the more I like it. If you were to show the main method rewritten to use an `AtomicInteger` as an answer, I can upvote it.

Comment: Hmm.. I very much prefer the version with a return value. More "functional".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to write this code is like this:

```
package controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DB {

    public interface StatementUser<T> {
        T run(Statement cmd);
    }

    public static <T> T runStatement(StatementUser<T> usingfunc) {
        try(Connection cnn = getConnection()){
            try(Statement stmt = cnn.createStatement()){
                return usingfunc.run(stmt);
            }
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ...; // someway to acquire a connection
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int affected = DB.runStatement(cmd -> {
            // do something with the statement
            return 10;
        });
        System.out.println(affected);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I saw this, I hand to hand-palm my forehead: somethings are so obvious (in hindsight). Thanks. BTW: I like the wrapping of the `SQLException`, that's a nice touch.

Comment: For people reading this in the future, Consider changing it to `runConnection`, there may (or may not) be benefits to having control over the creation of the statement.

Comment: I don't understand the `<T> T` syntax in the definition of runStatement. Could you please explain?